# В чем смысл создания плана обслуживания для выполнения одного execute?

Tags: sql-server, integration-services

Есть плановое задание в котором вызывается план обслуживания выполняющий лишь execute процедуры. 
В этом есть какой-то скрытый смысл или можно просто использовать для таких целей пункт "Сценарий T-SQL" вместо "Пакет служб SQL Server Integration Service"?

Comment: В планах обслуживания вообще нет смысла, имхо

Comment: Думаю что в вашем случае реализовали как смогли. Эти виды заданий предназначены для разных целей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае вы не получаете никаких преимуществ при использовании SSIS пакета, но при  усложнении логики работы вашего плана обслуживания вы можете получить дополнительные преимущества:

- Задание цепочки выполнения и изменение поведения при разных результатах выполнения предыдущих заданий (успех или ошибка).
- Управление последовательностью запуска заданий со сложными зависимостями между заданиями и т.д.